# Indent output of #system

Tags: ruby

I use `system` in a ruby script and I want to indent the output of the subshell of the `system` method.

`system("echo 'hello'")`

`$    hello`

I would like to use `system` because it uses a subshell and doesn't just store the result in a string like backticks do.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: provide test input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to `sed` through the shell like this. For example using the `ls` command:

```
system("ls | sed 's/^/  /g'")
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the pipe waits for the command to finish before executing sed. I am looking for a way of doing this 'in realtime' if it is possible.

Comment: I am actually trying with `software update -ia` on macOS but it should be the same for every similar commands.